# s = requests.Session() How do I get the cookie value for the session within my script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I tried:

```
login_data_2['_sn'] = s.__attrs__[1]
```

but this didn't work. pydoc has the following:

```
__attrs__ = ['headers', 'cookies', 'auth', 'timeout', 'proxies', 'hook..
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using Python Requests: Sessions, Cookies, and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778466/using-python-requests-sessions-cookies-and-post?rq=1)

> login_data_2['_sn'] = s.cookies['_sn']