# How to know which cookies to save using Python BeautifulSoup Library

Tags: python

I am logging into a website using the code below:

```s
s.get("https://my.epitomax.net/epitomax/login.jsp")

s.post("https://my.epitomax.net/epitomax/login.jsp", data={'_username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'})
```

Once logged in I am trying to navigate to a specific part of the webpage and read it for all links. When I get the webpage and download the links it doesn't occur within the session that I logged into thus acting as though I am signed out. Here is the code I have been using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_all_links(url):
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    links = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            href = link['href']
            if href and not href.startswith('#'):
                links.append(href)
    return links

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://my.epitomax.net/epitomax/document/CaseDocuments.jsp?case_no=100578'
    links = get_all_links(url)
    print(links)
```

Edit: I understand now that I need to save the cookies from my session and have tried to use beautiful soup to save the cookies.

To do this I followed this post: [Performing Login with Python requests (Cookies not activated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122379/performing-login-with-python-requests-cookies-not-activated)

However, I am unsure how to know which cookies to save. How do I know what variable to scrap for that will keep me logged in?

Comment: When you login, you have to save the session cookie and send it back when you go to other pages.