# Which python library can perform a complex `wget` operation?

Tags: python, wget, zabbix

I'm connecting to Zabbix, but since it doesn't provide an API for one of the resources I want, I had to use `wget` to get the job done.

Which python library would allow me to perform a "complex" `wget` operation?

By "complex," I mean:

```
 # Logging in to Zabbix
 wget -4 --no-check-certificate --save-cookies=z.coo -4 --keep-session-cookies -O - -S --post-data='name=username&password=somepassword&enter=Sign in&autologin=1&request=' 'https://some.zabbix-site.com:50100/index.php?login=1'

 # Grabbing the network image
 wget -4 --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=z.coo -O result.png 'https://some.zabbix-site.com:50100/map.php?sysmapid=5&severity_min=0'
```

Not sure if [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) would get the job done? I need to 1) login and save the returned cookies, 2) use the returned cookie to authenticate and retrieve the image.

Comment: `requests` can handle this perfectly well. You could use a `requests`' `Session` mechanism to deal with the cookies automatically.

Comment: Great, thanks. Your comment led me to this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778466/using-python-requests-sessions-cookies-and-post

Comment: @ForceBru thanks for your suggestion. I got the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @ForceBru for your suggestion. I managed to work out the solution now! Here it is:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
data = {'name': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'enter': 'Sign in', 'autologin': '1', 'request': ''}
url = 'https://some.zabbix-site.com:50100/index.php?login=1'
r = s.post(url, data=data)  # use this if the SSL certificate is valid
r = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False)  # use this if the SSL certificate is unsigned
r.cookies  # check the cookies value
re = s.get('https://some.zabbix-site.com:50100/map.php?sysmapid=5&severity_min=0')
re.content  # the file content is here!
```

References:

- Learn more about [Requests Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).
- Example of using [Requests to get Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778466/using-python-requests-sessions-cookies-and-post)
- How to get the [file content from Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)