# Python: requests can't login to a website

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I need to scrape website that requires login. I'm trying to create a `session` and login as I have to scrape different pages after logging in. But can't find out why it's not working.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_data = {
           "log":"login",
           "login":"my email",
           "password":"my password"
}

session = requests.session()
session.post(login_url, data=login_data)
response = session.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.title.get_text())
```

Title shows it's not working.

Here is the website form.

```
<form method="post" id="signin-form" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email_text" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Your login (email):</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_text" value="" name="login" autofocus data-validation='{"parent":".form-group","events":["keyup","blur"],"rules":[{"name":"notblank"},{"name":"email"}]}' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password_text" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_text" name="password" data-validation='{"parent":".form-group","rules":[{"name":"min","min":5}]}' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> Remember me on this computer
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="log">Log into your account</button>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg mobile-show-inline-block" href="/account/create/">Create account</a>
            <a href="/account/lostpassword" class="btn btn-link btn-lg">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

N.B: Don't suggest me to use `selenium`. I can do this with `selenium` and I tested that but I have to stick to `requests` because `selenium` pops up console even if I use `PhantomJS`.

Comment: Try doing a get on the login page first.  Perhaps it's setting some cookies that it expects to be present on the post.

Comment: @JohnGordon WOW !! That works. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try doing a get on the login page first. Perhaps it's setting some cookies that it expects to be present on the post.

Comment: Can you help me a bit more ? It's working when I'm doing this from a normal script, but when I'm trying to login and scrape from view of a django project it's not working. Can you tell why ?

Comment: Can we move to chat ?

Answer (score 6):

I know that this question was made long ago, but anyway, I'll propose a solution for those who are still having trouble with this:
I recommend to check if the form you are trying to post takes some kind of hidden input, which the example of the question does. This is very frequent, and does sometimes prevent us from logging to a site if we do not notice it. 
So, let's suppose in the site there is a form like this:

```
<form method='post' id='signin-form' class='big-form'>
 <input type="hidden" id="whatever" name="foo" value="check">
 <input type="text" id="u" name="user">
 <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pass">
</form>
```

In that case, the variable `login_data` should be like this:

```
login_data = {
       "foo":"check",
       "user":"your username",
       "pass":"your password",           
}
```

Having done this, and provided the website does not check the headers, you should have no trouble logging to a website via the requests module.

Comment: What if the value of value attribute(In your example 'check') is set at the moment of submission. In that case this this doesn't work. In some websites, they set the value of hidden elements when clicking the submit button. Do you have any solution for that also.

Comment: @sahan If you know beforehand what the value of `foo` will be (i.e. you know how it is generated), then you just have to send it. Things can get trickier though if that hidden input is specifically intended to prevent people from logging to the website and. In such a case, there is no general solution. What I suggest is that you check where that value comes from, and whether or not it is feasible to "generate" it from your code, because, as I said, if that value is generated in a manner complex enough (e.g. a captcha), what you want can be quite difficult (if not impossible) to achieve.

Comment: Then login into the site I am trying to login is not only not hard, probably impossible. That site generates values like hash with too complex AJAX. Can't even imagine a way to get those values. But, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing some headers. I would intercept a request made by a web browser to see the things you are missing, then add these headers to your request.

You will find information on how to do it on the official documentation, right here : https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#custom-headers

Comment: How to add headers ? Shouldn't it work without headers ? :/

Comment: It really depends on the server you are calling. A growing number of websites are now blocking request that are not coming with a browser's header for example.

In python requests, you can add a dict containing your headers as parameter to your post request, the kwarg is named 'headers' (without the quotes).