# How do you submit a response to a google form that requires a google account login using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-forms

I am able to use a PUSH request to submit responses to open google forms but when I do it for a form with login required, I get a 401 unauthorised error returned and nothing is submitted. Is there some way to include authentication credentials with the push request or an alternative way altogether to submit forms responses like this?

Comment: Firms with such behavior usually have API, your should have too.

Comment: i seem to vaguely recall you can do it if you have a cookie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15778466/7540911) is a similar question

Comment: @ZavenZareyan are you saying google has an api to fill out google forms?

Comment: For example use want to use GMail, google has api for it, want to use GoogleDrive, there's api, what you want?

Comment: Google forms, as in the surveys