# How can I check that I logged in correctly with python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm pretty new in python requests, and I have made a simple program, just to login, in netflix.
Here's my code.

```
url = 'https://www.netflix.com/login'

headers = {
'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.post(url, data={'userLoginId':'my-email', 'password': 'my-password'}, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

The output of status code is 200, so it's right

Comment: You should check status codes meaning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and also open the network tab on your browser console, login on netflix and compare if `200` is the status code it returns when logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Session to check the results of your login.

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, data={'userLoginId':'my-email', 'password': 'my-password'}, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

Then you could check the cookies for your session with:

```
s.cookies.getdict()
```

Another example in this question:
[Using Python Requests: Sessions, Cookies, and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778466/using-python-requests-sessions-cookies-and-post)

Comment: The output is it: <RequestsCookieJar[]>
But if I change the password, its the same.
`s = requests.Session()
r = requests.post(url, data={'userLoginId':'email', 'password': 'password'}, headers=headers)
print(s.cookies)`

Comment: Sorry, `s.cookies` will return the object, but not the value. Use `s.cookies.get_dict()` to get the dictionary value of your cookies. I have updated my answer!

Comment: The output of `s.cookies.getdict()` is `{}`