# Python Session post doesn't open my web browser

Tags: python, web, python-requests

I want to do a post request on a website with Python.
Here is the code

```
with requests.Session( ) as s:
    s.get(url)
    logdata = {'login': 'xxx', 'password': 'xxx'}

    s.post(url,data=log_data)
    r=s.get(url)
```

I remembered these lines were enough to open the url with the good login data but it seems not.
Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `GET` and not a `POST` in your code - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15794896/2590615 for `POST` example.

Also your variable `r` will only contain the server response as a string.

If you want to open your web browser with URL you must call your browser application from your code and give an URL as parameter - I do not know if it possible to apply post parameters in this way (I do not think so) .

So I would suggest to

- change your code and POST your wanted data and use still `r` to hold server  response
- write content of `r` into a file (e.g. `~/result-post.html` when response is HTML)
- call your browser application with file location (e.g. `firefox ~/result-post.html`) - or process the output programmatically